# Camera that pivots in the direction that the player is moving

Tags: unity, c#, camera

I'm trying to recreate Rocket League's freeform (non ball-locked) camera, which basically is a camera that follows the player but pivots to allows face the direction the player is moving in (not necessarily facing). Here's a video of Rocket League's implementation for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSpB6ocrIX8&t=37s

What are the main things needed to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you taken a look at existing tutorials or [previous questions about implementing a follow-cam behaviour](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67010/rotate-camera-as-an-object-manoeuvres) for some starting points? What have you tried based on your research so far?

Answer (score 0):

In UE4 i think you could create this quite easily using either a camera that is independent from the player (in that case you would use LERPs to rotate and move the camera). Spawn the camera in a fixed spot behind the player (but do not parent it to the player) and then rotate it at the player over time with a slight lag. Do the same with position.

Another way would be to use "Boom" to connect it to the player. The first solution you could translate to Unity quite easily, I don't know about the Boom part.